# Set of disjoint circles of radius $1$ on the plane countable?

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals

Give is a set of disjoint circles of radius $1$ on the plane. Is this set countable ? I don't think so. In my opinion, the set with only one circle with radius 1in the plane is also uncountable, isn't it?

Comment: I think you might misunderstand the question. Of course as you say a circle (of radius 1) is uncountable, but the question is not about the cardinality of the union of the circles, but the cardinality of the set of the circles. In your example that would be 1.

Comment: If $C$ is a circle then  yes, $C$ is uncountable. That's irrelevant - the question is whether $\{C\}$ is countable (clearly yes,  since $\{C\}$ has only **one** element).

Answer (score 3):

The hint:

Inside any circle we can take a rational point. It's one to one and ...